# Error javax/xml/namespace/QName when send email Amazon SES in richfaces

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, richfaces, amazon-ses

My project use richfaces framework. I try to integrate library [AWS SDK for Java version 1.8.9.1](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java). I try send email follow : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-java.html.
Error at function :**client.sendEmail(request);** (but email is still sent !).
This is detail error :

```
ERROR [application] java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException... 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException......
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/namespace/QName....
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/mx/loading/UnifiedClassLoader3) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/xml/namespace/QName"
............
```

And these is list library i have add to my project :

```
aspectjrt.jar
aspectjweaver.jar
aws-java-sdk-1.8.9.1.jar
aws-java-sdk-1.8.9.1-javadoc.jar
aws-java-sdk-1.8.9.1-sources.jar
aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools-1.8.9.1.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
freemarker-2.3.18.jar
httpclient-4.2.3.jar
httpcore-4.2.jar
jackson-annotations-2.1.1.jar
jackson-core-2.1.1.jar
jackson-databind-2.1.1.jar
joda-time-2.2.jar
mail-1.4.3.jar
spring-beans-3.0.7.jar
spring-context-3.0.7.jar
spring-cor
e-3.0.7.jar
```

How can i fix it ?

Comment: Try updating your commons-codec jar version. 1.3 is old. I had a similar problem and using a specific aws sdk version with a specific commons-codec version fixed it

Comment: Thank for your anwer. I have see my problem. That is third-party library conflict with my old library. I deleted 2 old lirary jaxrpc.jar and stax-api.jar it work ok